# permission denied error to github service

Tags: angularjs

I am following example on pluralsight.com website. Course name is Angularjs get started.

I get error on line `return $http.get(repoUrl + "/collaborators");`

Error is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular-seed/collaborators`

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQXRqO0hY3JGEIEcauVE)

To get to that error. Click on any user on link when data loads up after 5 seconds.

Comment: do you actually have permission to access that resource?  Checking the URL you have posted here in postman, it definitely returns "Requires Authentication", it's not a public API.

Comment: looks like you need to read this blog https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-06-24-api-enhancements-for-working-with-organization-permissions/ ..Looks like there is permissions policy changes on github

Comment: @Claies i was just following example on video. Not sure why he used this api if its not public

Comment: @PankajParkar do i need permission to even view the collaborators. i am not adding or deleting anything. just reading